# AES encrypting a file using Karl Malbrain's code

Tags: c, encryption, aes

using [Karl Malbrain's](http://www.geocities.ws/malbrain/aestable_c.html) C AES implementation I want to encrypt files of variable length. However, using the code below results in a cipher with only 16 bytes of correctly encrypted bytes folowwing a number of 00-bytes and again the starting 16 bytes of the cipher.

Did I implement it falsely or is the AES implementation not intented to be used for input > 16 bytes?

Best regards,
-P

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "aes.h"
#include <string.h>


void encryptStuff(void){
    uint8_t  key[AES_KEY_LENGTH] = "diesisteintest!!";
    uint8_t  keyschedule[AES_KEY_LENGTH * AES_ROUNDS] = {0x00};
    uint8_t message[16] = {0x00};
    uint8_t cipher[16197] = {0x00};
    uint8_t i = 0;
    uint8_t buffer[16197] = {0x42};
    unsigned char filename[] = "test.bin";
    FILE *ptr;

    ptr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    i = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), ptr);
    printf("Read %d bytes from %s:\n", i, filename);
    for(i = 0; i<100;i++){
            printf("%02x ", buffer[i]);
    }   
    printf("\n", buffer);
    printf("\n[D] Running AES-128 encryption\n");
    aes_expand_key(key, keyschedule);
    aes_encrypt(buffer, keyschedule, cipher);
    printf("message: ");
    for(i = 0; i<AES_KEY_LENGTH; i++){
            printf("%02x", message[i]);
    }
    printf(" | cipher: ");
    for(i = 0; i<sizeof(cipher); i++){
            printf("%02x ", cipher[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}

int main(){
    encryptStuff(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that a call such as `aes_encrypt()` which doesn't take a length has no way of magically figuring out how much data to encrypt (unless it's a string for instance). That's a clue that the input length is fixed-size.

Answer (score 0):

As with all **block** ciphers (as DES, AES, RSA, ...) they all encrypt your data one **block** at a time. For AES-128 it's exactly 16 bytes. So yes, you have to encrypt your data 16 bytes at a time.

Check out [Block cipher mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) for various block cipher modes that are in use.